# Error while Sending authorization headers in RSpec's Request Spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I am getting the following error while trying to send http headers using RSpec's request spec

```
 Failure/Error: request.env["HTTP_AUTHORIZATION"] = ""
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `env' for nil:NilClass
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can set an HTTP header while testing your controllers like this:

```
post :action, params, session, {"HTTP_AUTHORIZATION" = ""}
```

Comment: Well, this is actually a request spec and not a controller spec and the above doesn't work for me!

Comment: @MadhanPadmanabhan what is your rspec version? what about `@request.env["HTTP_AUTHORIZATION"] = ""` ?